# PDO - run unprepared statement containing "?"

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am trying to run a select query on a PostgreSQL database, to check for presence of a json field:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE meta ? 'linked_accounts'`

However PDO won't allow me to execute it raw:

```
<?php
$pdo     = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$query  = $pdo->query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE meta ? 'linked_accounts'" );

$users = $query->fetchAll();
```

Exception:

```
[PDOException]                                                         
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"  
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE meta $1 'linked_accounts' 
                                       ^
```

Comment: You missed the equal sign. and what is this supposed to do 'linked_accounts'

Comment: I'm doing the query on a json field!

Comment: thanks @aynber jsonb_exists did it for me